# Configure antMatchers in Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have this Spring Security configuration in Wildfly server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(value= {Application.class, ContextDatasource.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"org.rest.api.server.*"})
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired 
    private RestAuthEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/v1/notification")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

I want to configure Spring security to permit all requests send to
`http://localhost:8080/war_package/v1/notification` but unfortunately I get always Unauthorized. Do you know what is the proper way to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable ResourceServer and add configure(HttpSecurity http) there.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/v1/notification")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    }

}
```